# Create or launch Android emulator from terminal with animations disabled for Espresso testing

Tags: android, terminal, android-emulator, android-espresso

Does anyone know if it is possible to either create or launch an Android emulator from the terminal with the animation scale set to 0 so that I can automate the running of Espresso tests? The only command I can find in the 'emulator' documentation is to disable the boot animation, which doesn't really help.
It looks like I might be able to use:

```
adb shell settings put system window_animation_scale 0
```

after the emulator launches, but this doesn't seem to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful tools on Internet that can help you.

1. [test-butler](https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler)

   This project help automate the tests by just adding one-liner to the Espresso tests rule. But first you have to install external test-butler app in order to use it. However that fits into your requirements as you can earlier prepare the emulator image and start it from command line. More info [here](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/08/introducing-and-open-sourcing-test-butler--reliable-android-test)
2. [DeviceAnimationTestRule](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/DeviceAnimationTestRule)

   Apply another JUnit Rule to your tests and thhat at

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 animation types. You should disable all of them as below:

`adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0` 
`adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0.0`
`adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0.0`

More information here - [prepare android emulator for UI test automation.](https://testyour.app/blog/emulator)